# How to Count Item Monthwise

Tags: python, django

I try to make a bar chart and I want value month wise for last 6 months

my **models.py**

```
class Btdetail(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    BatType = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=1)
    MaxVolt = models.IntegerField()
    DatePurchase = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    Manf_ID = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

here is my **view.py**, this count all item of last six months but I want month wise data for last six months

```
def index_view(request):
    months_before = 5
    now = datetime.utcnow()
    from_datetime = now - relativedelta(months=months_before)
    modified_from_datetime = from_datetime.replace(day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
    month_count = Btdetail.objects.filter(DatePurchase__gte=modified_from_datetime).count()
    return render(request, "index.html", {'month_count': month_count})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I solved this by myself and get data monthly wise,  "any_variable6" mean the month before 6 month from the current month and so on

and you can also get idea how to get data from previous specific month

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def index_view(request, x=0, y=0):

    now = datetime.now()
    month6 = now - relativedelta(months=5)
    modified6 = month6.replace(day=1)
    month5 = now - relativedelta(months=4)
    modified5 = month5.replace(day=1)
    month4 = now - relativedelta(months=3)
    modified4 = month4.replace(day=1)
    month3 = now - relativedelta(months=2)
    modified3 = month3.replace(day=1)
    month2 = now - relativedelta(months=1)
    modified2 = month2.replace(day=1)
    month1 = now - relativedelta(months=0)
    modified1 = month1.replace(day=1)
    mon6 = Btdetail.objects.filter(DatePur__range=[modified6, modified5]).count()
    mon5 = Btdetail.objects.filter(DatePur__range=[modified5, modified4]).count()
    mon4 = Btdetail.objects.filter(DatePur__range=[modified4, modified3]).count()
    mon3 = Btdetail.objects.filter(DatePur__range=[modified3, modified2]).count()
    mon2 = Btdetail.objects.filter(DatePur__range=[modified2, modified1]).count()
    mon1 = Btdetail.objects.filter(DatePur__range=[modified1, now]).count()

    context = {
        'mon6': mon6,
        'mon5': mon5,
        'mon4': mon4,
        'mon3': mon3,
        'mon2': mon2,
        'mon1': mon1
    }
return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0):

view.py

```
month_count = Btdetail.objects.filter(DatePurchase__gte=modified_from_datetime)
```

index.html

```
{{month_count.count}}
```

Comment: I already did this if you notice and as I explain I don't need data of all six months I need data monthly wise mean separate data for current month and separate for previous month and so on